# Javascript can't find the script tag's id

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am facing problem with javascript document.getElementByID function. The HTML file is:

```
...
<script 
   id="scriptID"
   type="text/javascript"
   src="http://external.script.com/file.js">
</script>
...
```

When the page is loaded, the script is successfully included, but when executing expression from that file (the script is executed automaticaly after loading it):

```
... = document.getElementById('scriptID').src
```

The script fails with message saying that "document.getElementById('scriptID') is null".
Can anybody tell me, why it is null if the tag is the script tag itself?

Thx for any response.

EDIT:
I don't know if that is relevant, but the page is built in a bit more complicated way.
There is page of some product. When the customer orders that product, there is a div loaded by AJAX with some "Thanks for order" and that contains the script. Then the script is executed.

Comment: Where are you running this script?

Comment: Are you certain this is the **only** element with that ID on the page?

Comment: So... You're referring to the script tag from within the script that is running in that tag? Hmm. Probably a matter of the DOM not being fully parsed, specifically... That script tag, since you're executing  the script within it.

Comment: This behavior could be browser dependent. Let us know which browser and version you are using.

Comment: The script is somewhere in the middle of a page. I am sure, that the id is unique and I am using Firefox 25.0.

Comment: well actualy the script is running after it's loading into the page by ajax (see my edit above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your DOM is not ready when you are try to get src of script,

```
<script id="scriptID" type="text/javascript" src="http://external.script.com/file.js">
</script>

window.onload=function()
{
 alert( document.getElementById('scriptID').src);   
}
```

Its workinfg fine **[SEE](http://jsfiddle.net/BXT2R/)**

Comment: actualy it does not get the element at all - because the result of getElementById is null

Comment: @Jarda If you are downloading script with ajax, then use dom method to create script ex: createElement('script').